# SELECT AVG number of connections per day

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I want to calculate the average number of connections per day to an Azure SQL Database.

This query return the `SUM` per day

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) -- 1 Days

SELECT database_name
    ,CAST(start_time AS DATE) AS start_time2
    ,SUM(success_count) AS Connections
FROM sys.database_connection_stats
WHERE start_time > @StartDate
GROUP BY database_name
    ,CAST(start_time AS DATE)
ORDER BY Connections DESC
```

It returns a dataset like this:

| database_name | start_time2 | Connections |
| --- | --- | --- |
| qav10auto1 | 2022-10-02 | 793 |
| qav10ptweu | 2022-10-02 | 482 |
| qav10ptweu | 2022-10-03 | 409 |
| qa0r0auto1 | 2022-10-02 | 271 |
| qav10auto2 | 2022-10-02 | 266 |

If I put `AVG` instead of `SUM` it returns:

| database_name | start_time2 | Connections |
| --- | --- | --- |
| qav10auto1 | 2022-10-02 | 5 |
| qav10daily1 | 2022-10-03 | 4 |
| qav10auto1 | 2022-10-03 | 3 |
| qa0r0auto2 | 2022-10-02 | 2 |
| qav10auto3 | 2022-10-03 | 2 |

And I know why!

This is because if you do `SELECT * FROM sys.database_connection_stats` you will notice that  Azure SQL Database sum the connections every 5 minutes so in the column success_count you will mostly have numbers between 1 and 20.

So how can I **aggregate** per day and then have the **average** per day.

Because the goal is to see, in a span of 30 days, how many connections each database receives per day.

Comment: Isn't this information available in the Azure Portal under Metrics or Monitors?

Comment: *"So how can I aggregate per day and then have the average per day."* Use a CTE or derived table.

Comment: Side note, looking at your questions you seem to be in the (bad) habit of putting tags in the title. *Tags* are for the tags, not the title and the [help] article [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) *explicitly* tells you to *not* put tags in the title unless they are "organic to the conversational tone of the title"; your usage is not organic. "AVG number of connections per day to an Azure SQL Database"  vs "Azure SQL Database :: SELECT AVG number of connections per day" 

Comment: Thank you @Dai , I need to run this query on large scale, I need a script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tonight I'm going to bad satisfied:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()) -- 1 Days

SELECT t.name
    ,round(avg(CAST(t.Count_Connections AS FLOAT)), 2) AS AVG_Connections_per_Hour
FROM (
    SELECT name
        --,database_name
        --,success_count
        --,start_time
        ,CONVERT(DATE, start_time) AS Dating
        ,DATEPART(HOUR, start_time) AS Houring
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN name = database_name
                    THEN success_count
                ELSE 0
                END) AS Count_Connections
    FROM sys.database_connection_stats
    CROSS JOIN sys.databases
    WHERE start_time > @StartDate
        AND database_id != 1
    GROUP BY name
        ,CONVERT(DATE, start_time)
        ,DATEPART(HOUR, start_time)
    ) AS t
GROUP BY t.name
```

I had the genius idea to use:

```
FROM sys.database_connection_stats
CROSS JOIN sys.databases
```

Because the two table are not the same I'm basically creating a bug where each row of `sys.databases` is selected every time there is a row in `sys.database_connection_stats`.

Then I use `CASE` to select the number of connections when there are connections and to put a `0` instead if there are no connections.

I removed the `master` database with `database_id != 1`.

And I rounded the number of connections with `round(avg(CAST(t.Count_Connections AS FLOAT)), 2)`.

I can now understand what Azure SQL Databases are good candidate for Serverless tier.